# Sentence meaning, relative and PP

Tags: meaning-in-context

> She followed the trail he breaks through the vines.

Is there a ***which*** or ***that*** between the word **trail** and **he**, but was omitted to make the sentence more concise?

> She followed the trail which/that he breaks through the vines.

And what does the PP here **through the vines** belong to, does it belong to **the trail** or the verb **breaks**?

Comment: @Arham yes, I heard of that, but as an english learner, the grammar is still quite abstract to me, so I posted the question here to check if I get the right idea of it.

Comment: "She followed the trail [(that/which) he breaks through the vines]." The bracketed element is a normal relative clause modifying "trail". "That" or "which" are  optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. She followed the trail.
> 2. He breaks the trail through the vines.

Combining these, we have

> She followed the trail [that/which] he breaks through the vines.